# learn tag/keyword from a sentence

Tags: machine-learning, clustering, svm, natural-language

I want a algorithm which can predict the tag from a sentence as given below then predict the same from new sentence.

For example (Learning Data):

1. Apple Iphone 6S - "Apple"
2. Samsung HDTV LED 1080px - "Samsung"
3. 21" Smart LG TV - "LG"

and so on..

Now given a new title like - 23" Sony LED TV - It should be able to predict Sony.

Comment: named entity recognition what the name for what you're interested in

Comment: I think so long as "I want an algorithm" is interpreted in a very general sense (not "show me the code" or "show me how to write a particular algorithm", just "give me a pointer to what's out there") the question is answerable without being too broad. In fact @GeneralAbrial's answer provides the core of an answer, and I think it would only take a few sentences/reference links to flesh it out a bit.

Comment: It does strike me that (a) the question as written is pretty clear, likely to be common, and has been written in a way that is easily searchable *by people who do not know the real name of what they're trying to achieve*, and (b) even the comment by GeneralAbrial is a good pointer that would add value to such future readers, and a brief answer even more so. As such I think it would be a shame for this thread to be lost, particularly if it was just over a minor quibble in the phrasing of what is being asked for.

Comment: @Silverfish I've been persuaded and have voted to reopen.

Comment: @GeneralAbrial, I just voted as well, so it is re-opened now, if you want to provide an answer.

Comment: @gung thanks for the heads-up. I'm encumbered from commenting further.